# Remove comma from substring in Python

Tags: python-3.x, substring, python-re, string-substitution

The string is the following:

```
s = 'AUDC,AUDIOCODES COM,+55,27.49,26.47,"$1,455.85",($56.10),($56.10),-3.71%'
```

I would like the comma inside this substring `"$1,455.85"` to be removed but not the other commas.

I tried this but failed:

```
import re
pattern = r'$\d(,)'

re.sub(pattern, '', s)
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a positive lookbehind assertion, i.e., match a comma if it is preceded by a `$` (note that `$` needs to be escaped as `\$`) followed by a digit (`\d`). Try:

```py
>>> s = 'AUDC,AUDIOCODES COM,+55,27.49,26.47,"$1,455.85",($56.10),($56.10),-3.71%'
>>> pattern = r'(?<=\$\d),'
>>> re.sub(pattern, '', s)
'AUDC,AUDIOCODES COM,+55,27.49,26.47,"$1455.85",($56.10),($56.10),-3.71%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
pattern = r"(\$\d+),"
s = 'AUDC,AUDIOCODES COM,+55,27.49,26.47,"$1,455.85",($56.10),($56.10),-3.71%'
print(s)
s = re.sub(pattern, r'\1', s)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
AUDC,AUDIOCODES COM,+55,27.49,26.47,"$1,455.85",($56.10),($56.10),-3.71%
AUDC,AUDIOCODES COM,+55,27.49,26.47,"$1455.85",($56.10),($56.10),-3.71%
```

But it doesn't work for "$1,455,789.85"

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it. And if it doesn't work for certain inputs, then it is not the correct answer.